# R: import CSV but why show differently?

Tags: r, csv

I got stuck when I imported the data. The csv file has several columns. Some of them are numbers (e.g. salary) and some of them are text (e.g. job description).

I just typed in:

```
adz <- read.csv(file = "adz.csv", head = TRUE, sep=",")
```

When I viewed the dataset and scrolled down to the middle, all the cells are filled with text coming from "job description" column. What's the problem...? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Any improper formatting in the file can cause havoc with `read.csv`. So, hard to say why this would happen. Perhaps there is long text with commas in it, or new lines that get misread. Best to paste the problem lines from the csv here. You can may be use some unix utility to grab those lines?

Comment: add an example of your file including some lines that cause  a problem